# How to get available variations by product id with Rest api in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I tried the `get_available_variations ()` function but it is very slow as the product has many options, then I tried and the options available using rest api `/ wp-json / wc / v3 / products / productId / changes? Consumer_key = 'consumer_key' & consumer_secret = 'consumer_secret'` ', but it doesn't return the same response.

How can I get the available options using the rest api that will return a response like the `get_available_variations ()` function?
Thank you

Comment: What all data points you need which are available on `get_available_variations()` ???

Comment: @bhanu attributes

Comment: You want to get these values using REST API because it is slow, or that's the only way you want that data ?

Comment: @bhanubecause it is slow because the product has 2300 variations

Comment: `get_available_variations ()` is very slow on the product view page when the product has a lot of options